# Sitecore User Group July 2019 Meetup - Queen City, Manchester, NH

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

We are wicked jazzed to announce the July'19 meetup of the Queen City Sitecore User Group!

Two excellent presentation are lined up for this SUG:

Rule Based Contact Profiling: Achieve 100% contact profiling coverage with a single pipeline extension, no content tagging & cloud services by Nick Allen, Technical Architect & Digital Consultant at Think Fresh Studio and Sitecore Technology MVP

Fun with Sitecore JSS: Exploring GraphQL by Adam Lamarre, Principal Developer at Velir and Sitecore Technology MVP

Date & Time (EST):- Wednesday, July, 10, 2019 6:00 PM

Date & Time (UTC):- Wednesday, July, 10, 2019 10:00 PM

Venue:- SilverTech Inc, 196 Bridge Street, Manchester, NH 03104

[Click here](https://www.meetup.com/Queen-City-Sitecore-User-Group/events/262689586/) for more details and RSVP.

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins in 13 hours.